# When I deploy war file on tomcat Server at that time ireport is not working but when I run it on my local tomcat server ireport work properly

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jasper-reports, tomcat7

I am working on club management system software in which I have to generate  report for different types, unfortunately I am not  able  to generate it on tomcat 7 on aws ec2 instance. When I run  it on server its showing only blank screen.  It is working fine on my local machine.

I googled this issue but no solution is working for me. Following are my code which I implemented. Any help will be great.

```
Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parametros.put("receipt_no", receiptno);
ServletOutputStream out = ((ServletResponse) response).getOutputStream();
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream url=null;

ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
//url=context.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/reports/hififym.jasper");
url = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/hififym.jasper");
JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(url);
Connection conn=DBConnection.getConnection();
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, conn);
conn.close();
JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: Check your log files in the ec2 instance? What does the stacktrace say? Is the file `/hififym.jasper` available?